# Clarification of MySQL DIV operator applied to non-integer values

Tags: mysql, math, sqldatatypes

Can someone please clarify how the MySQL DIV operator works, or is supposed to work, when its operands are NOT integers?

Supposedly it performs "integer division" - but when the operands aren't integers, it appears to behave like FLOOR(x/y) rather than (the expected) FLOOR(x) DIV FLOOR(y).

For example, using MySQL v5.5.37:

```
SELECT 5.6 DIV 5.7
SELECT 5.7 DIV 5.6
```

returns 0 and 1, respectively.

According to the MySQL manual:

> Integer division. Similar to FLOOR(), but is safe with BIGINT values.
>
> As of MySQL 5.5.3, if either operand has a noninteger type, the operands are converted to DECIMAL and divided using DECIMAL arithmetic before converting the result to BIGINT. If the result exceeds BIGINT range, an error occurs.

This is confusing, because I would expect "casting to decimal" would convert to an integer value, i.e.

```
SELECT CAST(5.4 AS DECIMAL)
SELECT CAST(5.6 AS DECIMAL)
```

results in "5" and "6" respectively.

A possible explanation is this (found elsewhere in the manual- section 12.2):

> As of MySQL 5.5.3, the server includes dtoa, a conversion library that provides the basis for improved conversion between string or DECIMAL values and approximate-value (FLOAT/DOUBLE) numbers:

. . .

> - F -> D conversion is done with the best possible precision, returning D as the shortest string that yields F when read back in and rounded to the nearest value in native binary format as specified by IEEE.

...So what this is suggesting to me is that the expression:

```
6.3 DIV 3.141592
```

is actually evaluated as:

```
FLOOR( (CAST (6.3 AS DECIMAL(65,1)) / (CAST (3.141592 AS DECIMAL(65,6))) )
```

Furthermore the manual (section 12.6.1) says:

> - In division performed with /, the scale of the result when using two exact-value operands is the scale of the first operand plus the value of the div_precision_increment system variable (which is 4 by default). For example, the result of the expression 5.05 / 0.014 has a scale of six decimal places (360.714286).

But it's not clear (to me) if this should apply to the intermediate division result when using DIV also.   Apparently it doesn't:

```
SELECT 1999999.9 / 1000000 
SELECT 1999999.9 DIV 1000000
```

results in "2.00000" and "1" respectively.

So "x DIV y" in MySQL appears to work like:

```
FLOOR( (CAST (x AS DECIMAL(65,x’s decimal places)) / (CAST (y AS DECIMAL(65,y’s decimal places))
```

...withn the caveat that there's no rounding off of the intermediate division result before FLOOR() is applied?

Can someone with knowledge of MySQL's actual specifications confirm, deny, comment, or elucidate on this?

I'm hesitant to use this operator without having 100% certainty in what it's doing, and the official documentation just does not provide an adequate explanation!

Comment: I would take into account the [handling of expressions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/precision-math-expressions.html) in precision math: *If any exact value contains a fractional part (a value following the decimal point), the expression is evaluated using DECIMAL exact arithmetic and has a precision of 65 digits.*

Comment: Simple solution:  Only use `div` on integer operands.  That is really what it is designed for.

Comment: @VMai:  Thanks!  I hadn't noticed that section, but it does indeed support my assumption about what DV does.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff:  <sarcasm> Gee, that's a really huge help... Where would we be without sage advice like that? </sarcasm>